# MySQL - Selecting the most recent post by each of the 10 most recent authors

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing blog posts by many different authors. What I'd like to do is show the most recent post by each of the 10 most recent authors.

Each author's posts are simply added to the table in order, which means there could be runs of posts by a single author. I'm having a heck of time coming up with a single query to do this.

This gives me the last 10 unique author IDs; can it be used as a sub-select to grab the most recent post by each author?

```
SELECT DISTINCT userid
FROM posts
ORDER BY postid DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select userid,postid, win from posts where postid in (
SELECT max(postid) as postid
FROM posts 
GROUP BY userid
) 
ORDER BY postid desc 
limit 10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/09e25/1

Comment: This is close - it returns the most recent postid for each userid, but  the rest of the data in the rows doesn't match. For example, this doesn't work:  SELECT userid, title, bodytext, MAX(id) id      FROM posts      GROUP BY userid      ORDER BY id DESC      LIMIT 10

Comment: right If you want all fields, unfortunately you need a subquery. I edited my answer.

Comment: Great, glad I helped. Accepting correct answer will be greater :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a subquery for the last postid of every author and order by postid DESC. Then, join that result to the `posts` table:

```
SELECT B.* FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM
    (
        SELECT userid,MAX(postid) postid
        FROM posts GROUP BY userid
    ) AA
    ORDER BY postid DESC
    LIMIT 10
) A INNER JOIN posts B
USING (user_id,post_id);
```

Make sure you have this index

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD INDEX user_post_ndx (userid,postid);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the compound index on userID, postID as the postID would be the unique identifier anyhow and would only exist for the one author doing the post.

Comment: @DRapp That compound index is needed to speed up the subquery AA (full index scan vs full table scan)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT userid
     , MAX(postid) AS lastpostid
FROM posts
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY lastpostid DESC 
LIMIT 10
```