# How can I query SQL for latest record with additional conditions

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I should find all active vm_id's for a certain date (2014-10-01), important I should reach only latest record per vm_id.

> date,action,vm_id,vm_status
>  2014-09-01
>   08:13:00,Creation,vm-4058,active
>  2014-09-04
>   10:13:00,Creation,vm-4059,active
>  2014-09-08
>   17:13:00,Deletion,vm-4059,cancelled
>  2014-09-30
>   09:13:00,Creation,vm-4057,active
>  2014-09-30
>   15:13:00,Modification,vm-4057,active
>  2014-10-23
>   08:13:00,Deletion,vm-4057,cancelled

I would like to fetch the latest record for all active subscription on 2014-10-01:

> 2014-09-01 08:13:00,Creation,vm-4058,active
>  2014-09-30
>   15:13:00,Modification,vm-4057,active

Does anyone know how to get there?

Comment: You can go to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998210/mysql-most-recent-enter-for-each-id/26004212#26004212 that explain more about the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Try this

select Max(date) as date, max(action)as action, vm_id, Max(vm_status) from [tablename]

where vm_status = 'active' and vm_id not in (select vm_id from [tablename] where vm_status ='cancelled')

group by vn_id

Comment: Also here very close, but it gives me only vm-4058 back and not vm-4059 which was deleted after '2014/10/01' and should be therefore returned.

Comment: OK, here even I was able to add the needed part:

select Max(date) as date, max(action)as action, vm_id, Max(vm_status) from t
where vm_status = 'active' and vm_id not in (select vm_id from t where vm_status ='cancelled' AND date < '2014/10/01')
group by vm_id

This it is! Muchos Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea.  Find the latest date, then find the record and determine if it is active.

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select vm_id, max(date) as maxdate
      from table t
      group by vm_id
     ) tt
     on t.vm_id = tt.vm_id and t.date = tt.maxdate
where t.status = 'active';
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, get the latest and greatest prior to your date, and make sure it's not a deletion.  Same idea as some of the other answers, just another way to do it.

select date,action,vm_id,vm_status from

```
(SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
        (
                PARTITION BY  A.vm_id
                ORDER BY      A.date DESC
        ) AS seq
FROM tablename where date < '2014/10/01') b
where seq = 1 and vm_status <> 'Deletion'
```

Comment: This is getting very close, but it does also display the vm-4059 which was cancelled before '2014/10/01' and is therefore not active anymore and should not be displayed.